# How to access multiprocessing.Manager().Namespace element remotely via SyncManager?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, synchronization, share, remote-access

No matter how hard I read the docs, I fail to understand how to use a SyncManager to access remotely an item of a multiprocessing Namespace.

Please note the code below is the shortest possible to demonstrate what works and what fails. The crux of my problem lies in the calls to `register`, which I fail to properly understand how to use.

The example below comprises of two parts (both in the same file `mp-example.py`): a server and a client. For the client part to do its work, the server part must be running (in another terminal/screen).

## First, the code that works:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import sys
import multiprocessing as mp
import multiprocessing.managers as mpm
import queue
import socket
import contextlib
from contextlib import contextmanager

def get_ip():
    with contextlib.closing(socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)) as s:
        s.connect(('192.168.17.1', 80))
        return s.getsockname()[0]

def get_free_port():
    with contextlib.closing(socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)) as s:
        s.bind(('', 0))
        s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        return s.getsockname()[1]

def startserver(name):
    # Find a free port for the SyncManager
    newportnumber = get_free_port()
    Server = {'address': (get_ip(), newportnumber), 'authkey': b'mptest'}

    # Save data to file
    serverdata_filename = f'mpSERVERDATA.txt'
    with open(serverdata_filename, 'wt', encoding="utf-8") as serverdata_file:
        print(Server, file=serverdata_file)
        print(Server)

    # On the server, we do not need our own IP address
    Server['address'] = ('', newportnumber)

    # Set up server:
    #   define a multiprocessing manager
    #   define a multipprocessing namespace
    #   define a Value item in the namespace
    #   define a Value item outside the namespace
    #   define a multiprocessing syncmanager
    #   start the syncmanager
    #   register both the namespace and the value outside the namespace
    #   set values
    #   initialise a different process
    #   print the values
    #   run the other process & wait for completion
    #   print the values
    #   read standard input & print the values (waiting for a remote process connection)

    m = mp.Manager()
    m.name = 'mp.Manager: ' + name

    with m:
        ns = m.Namespace()
        ns.name = 'm.Namespace: ' + name
        ns.yv = m.Value(int, 0)
        yv = m.Value(int, 0)

        bm = mpm.SyncManager(**Server)
        bm.name = 'mpm.SyncManager: ' + name

        #bm.register('ns', callable=lambda: ns, proxytype=mpm.NamespaceProxy,
        #            exposed=('__getattribute__', '__setattr__', '__delattr__', 'yv')
        #           )
        # The above has not made any difference
        bm.register('ns', callable=lambda: ns, proxytype=mpm.NamespaceProxy)
        bm.register('yv', callable=lambda: yv, proxytype=mpm.ValueProxy)

        with bm:
            yv.value = 99
            ns.yv = 999

            def f(n, y):
                n.yv += 222
                y.value += 33

            proc = mp.Process(target=f, args=(ns, yv))
            print(f'yv={yv}, ns.yv={ns.yv}')
            proc.start()
            proc.join()
            proc.terminate()
            print(f'yv={yv}, ns.yv={ns.yv}, ns={ns}')
            print('Waiting for input (waiting for client), press CTRL-D to end')
            for line in sys.stdin:
                print(f'yv={yv}, ns.yv={ns.yv}, ns={ns}')
                print('Waiting for input (waiting for client), press CTRL-D to end')

elif sys.argv[1] == 'server' and len(sys.argv) == 3:
    startserver(sys.argv[2])
elif sys.argv[1] == 'client' and len(sys.argv) == 3:
    startclient(sys.argv[2])
```

The code above does what I expect when run on its own:

```
> python3 mp-example.py server test
{'address': ('192.168.17.10', 50793), 'authkey': b'mptest'}
yv=Value(<class 'int'>, 99), ns.yv=999
yv=Value(<class 'int'>, 132), ns.yv=1221, ns=Namespace(name='m.Namespace: test', yv=1221)
Waiting for input (waiting for client), press CTRL-D to end
```

## Next, the bit that does not work:

The code below works up to a point, but fails when trying to access the Value item `yv` within the Namespace.

Code:

```
def startclient(name):
    # retrieve server identification from file
    serverdata_filename = f'mpSERVERDATA.txt'
    with open(serverdata_filename, 'rt', encoding="utf-8") as serverdata_file:
        Server = eval(serverdata_file.read())
        print(Server)

    bm = mpm.SyncManager(**Server)
    bm.register('yv', proxytype=mpm.ValueProxy)
    bm.register('ns', proxytype=mpm.NamespaceProxy)
    bm.connect()

    yv = bm.yv()
    print(f'yv={yv.value}')
    yv.value += 55
    print(f'yv={yv.value}')

    ns = bm.ns()
    print(f'ns={ns}')
    print(f'ns.yv={ns.yv}')
    ns.yv += 666
    print(f'ns.yv={ns.yv}')
```

Output:

```
> python3 mp-example.py client test
{'address': ('192.168.17.10', 50793), 'authkey': b'mptest'}
yv=627
yv=682
['_Client', '__class__', '__deepcopy__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattr__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_address_to_local', '_after_fork', '_authkey', '_callmethod', '_close', '_connect', '_decref', '_exposed_', '_getvalue', '_id', '_idset', '_incref', '_manager', '_mutex', '_owned_by_manager', '_serializer', '_tls', '_token']
Help on method _getvalue in module multiprocessing.managers:

_getvalue() method of multiprocessing.managers.NamespaceProxy instance
    Get a copy of the value of the referent

None
ns=<NamespaceProxy object, typeid 'Namespace' at 0x7f5d05689a20>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mp-example.py", line 333, in <module>
    startclient(sys.argv[2])
  File "mp-example.py", line 282, in startclient
    print(f'ns.yv={ns.yv}')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 1060, in __getattr__
    return callmethod('__getattribute__', (key,))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 772, in _callmethod
    raise convert_to_error(kind, result)
AttributeError: 'NamespaceProxy' object has no attribute 'yv'
```

## Question:

What do I need to do to access `ns.yv` in the client?

Comment: Shortest code necessary please

Comment: That is the shortest code I was able to come up with for a fully functioning example. My actual code is 20 times longer at least.

Comment: I don't know if it is important but in server code there is `ns = m.Namespace()` which means the namespace is created by manager "m" instead of "bm". This may create confusion when the namespace uses a different manager for its synchronization.

Comment: I struggled with this a lot. The problem is that to register an object for remote use it must be available before you start the manager, so if you want to share a manager created object, you must have two managers: one to create the objects, the second one to act as a remote server and share. Or so I understand. If there is a shortcut, I'd love to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Edit - comprehensive solution:

I resolved most of my frustrations by writing a new `RemoteSyncManager` class to encapsulate the `multiprocessing.managers.SyncManager()` instance.

This library of mine really simplifies the use of the `SyncManager` both for local and remote processes.

Head over to my GitHub repository [PythonLibraries-Multiprocessing-RemoteSyncManager](https://github.com/apmcgh/PythonLibraries-Multiprocessing-RemoteSyncManager) for details.

## My first solution:

I finally managed to set-up a Managed multiprocessing Namespace that synchronises with a remote connection.

But this set-up refuses to work with Managed dict, it works in a similar way to Booboo's suggestion, above.

Is there any way to define and keep synchronised a whole dict in a remotely shared namespace without having to re-assign the dict at every operation?

Code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    if sys.argv[1] == 'Server' and len(sys.argv) == 2:
        #localmanager = mp.Manager()
        #with localmanager:
        q1 = mp.Queue(1)
        q2 = mp.Queue(1)
        localnamespace = mpm.Namespace()
    
        class syncmanager(mpm.SyncManager):
            pass
        syncmanager.register('get_q1', callable=lambda: q1)
        syncmanager.register('get_q2', callable=lambda: q2)
        syncmanager.register('get_ns', callable=lambda: localnamespace, proxytype=mpm.NamespaceProxy)
    
        remotemanager = syncmanager(address = ('', 56789), authkey = b'mypassword')
        remotemanager.start()
    
        with remotemanager:
            ns = remotemanager.get_ns()
            #ns.sampledict = remotemanager.dict()
            ns.sampledict = {}
            #ns.sampledict = localmanager.dict()
            ns.sampledict['testabc'] = 1234567
            ns.sampledict['TESTABC'] = 9876
            d = {}
            d['testabc'] = 1234567
            d['TESTABC'] = 9876
            ns.sampledict2 = d
    
            print(f'Server ns = {ns}')
    
            print(q2.get())
            q1.put(f'Server ns = {ns}')
    
            ns.sampledict['testabc'] = 1
            ns.sampleserverint = 98789
            print(f'Server ns = {ns}')
    
            print(q2.get())
            q1.put(f'Server ns = {ns}')
    
    elif sys.argv[1] == 'Client' and len(sys.argv) == 2:
        class syncmanager(mpm.SyncManager):
            pass
        syncmanager.register('get_q1')
        syncmanager.register('get_q2')
        syncmanager.register('get_ns', proxytype=mpm.NamespaceProxy)
    
        remotemanager = syncmanager(address = ('', 56789), authkey = b'mypassword')
        remotemanager.connect()
    
        q1 = remotemanager.get_q1()
        q2 = remotemanager.get_q2()
        ns = remotemanager.get_ns()
    
        q2.put('ready')
        msg = q1.get()
        print(msg)
        print(f'Client ns = {ns}')
    
        ns.sampledict['TESTABC'] = 9
        ns.sampleclientint = 7887
    
        q2.put('next.1')
        msg = q1.get()
        print(msg)
        print(f'Client ns = {ns}')
```

Answer (score 2):

I struggled mightily with it, too -- it's difficult to come up with any solution along the lines you are following that isn't convoluted and inefficient. As an aside, you are attempting to return a proxy to a shared memory value, which is already shareable without requiring a proxy and if your goal is to just serve up a singleton value, there is no need for it to be in shared memory.

A simpler approach, which does not require you to create two manager processes just so you can create a proxy object that can then be registered with another manager before you start it, is to just define your own custom classes. You typically create your own subclass of `multiprocessing.managers.BaseManager` with which you will register your new managed classes (of course, if your client also needs the classes already registered with the `SyncManager`, e.g. a `dict`, then you would subclass that).

The following program shows how you create a singleton `Namespace` equivalent type. I commented out your IP address and used `127.0.0.1` for testing. I also replaced your call to `eval` with a safer substitute.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import sys
import multiprocessing as mp
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager, NamespaceProxy
import socket
import contextlib
from ast import literal_eval
from threading import Thread


def get_ip():
    with contextlib.closing(socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)) as s:
        #s.connect(('192.168.17.1', 80))
        s.connect(('127.0.0.1', 80))
        return s.getsockname()[0]

def get_free_port():
    with contextlib.closing(socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)) as s:
        s.bind(('', 0))
        s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        return s.getsockname()[1]

class MyNamespaceManager(BaseManager):
    pass

class MyNamespace:
    pass

# Singleton:
singleton = MyNamespace()

def get_singleton():
    return singleton

def run_server(server):
    server.serve_forever()

def startserver():
    # Find a free port for the SyncManager
    newportnumber = get_free_port()
    Server = {'address': (get_ip(), newportnumber), 'authkey': b'mptest'}

    # Save data to file
    serverdata_filename = f'mpSERVERDATA.txt'
    with open(serverdata_filename, 'wt', encoding="utf-8") as serverdata_file:
        print(Server, file=serverdata_file)
        print(Server)

    # On the server, we do not need our own IP address
    Server['address'] = ('', newportnumber)

    # Singleton
    MyNamespaceManager.register('MyNamespace', callable=get_singleton, proxytype=NamespaceProxy)

    manager = MyNamespaceManager(**Server)
    """
    manager.start()
    input('Hit enter to end: ')
    manager.shutdown()
    """
    server = manager.get_server()
    Thread(target=run_server, args=(server,)).start()
    try:
        input('Hit enter to end: ')
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    os.unlink(serverdata_filename)
    server.stop_event.set() # The server stops and calls sys.exit()

def startclient():
    # retrieve server identification from file
    serverdata_filename = f'mpSERVERDATA.txt'
    with open(serverdata_filename, 'rt', encoding="utf-8") as serverdata_file:
        Server = literal_eval(serverdata_file.read())
        print(Server)

    MyNamespaceManager.register('MyNamespace', proxytype=NamespaceProxy)
    manager = MyNamespaceManager(**Server)
    manager.connect()

    yv1 = manager.MyNamespace()
    yv1.value = 99
    yv1.value += 55
    yv1.x = 9

    yv2 = manager.MyNamespace()
    print(f'yv2.value={yv2.value}')
    print(f'yv2.x={yv2.x}')


if __name__ == '__main__':

    if len(sys.argv) == 2 and sys.argv[1] == 'server':
        startserver()
    else:
        startclient()
```

The client prints:

```
{'address': ('127.0.0.1', 51211), 'authkey': b'mptest'}
yv2.value=154
yv2.x=9
```

Comment: You say "**As an aside, you are attempting to return a proxy to a shared memory value, which is already shareable without requiring a proxy**", I would very much like to understand this statement of yours in detail. How can I use a multiprocessor Namespace without passing by a Manager to share data (anything, including dicts, possibly nested) between separate processes? Or indeed is there a better way to do this? I have to admit to being utterly confused with proxies.

Comment: P.S. the purpose of the namespace, as I see it, is to gather a number of variables under one hat. I now realise that I could share each individually, but that requires more leg work. The python docs state clearly that a SyncManager can be used to register a Namespace, I just have not found a way to make it work yet.

Comment: See my code for class `IntValue`; it is a plain class whose objects reside in non-shared memory that belongs to a process that is started when you either call `start` on a manger or call `serve_forever` on the server that is returned by the call `get_server` on a manager. The proxy object that is created for it which can be passed to other processes (i.e. address spaces) exposes proxy methods that are the same. But when you call the methods on the proxy, it results in sending a message via a socket to the server where the actual method call is made on the real object. (more...)

Comment: So that is one way of sharing data among processes, i.e. as managed objects, which has performance issues because of the messaging used to implement method calls. The other way is to create data in shared memory and just pass references to that data. A `multiprocessing.Value` is a shared memory data item and a reference to it can be passed to another process and modified directly without using extra manager processors; it's already sharable. That's all I was saying. (more...)

Comment: Ok, the fog in my head clears a bit. But presumably I still need one Manager to share the Value, right?

Comment: You can ask the SyncManager for a Namespace instance and pass it around -- no problem. But you don't normally try to create a new type of managed object that contains a Namespace object or you run into the types of problems you are attempting. My `IntValue` class uses the NamespaceProxy to build if you will a specialized type of `Namespace` that comes with `value` predefined. But I could add any new attributes in client, e.g. `yv1.x = 9`. It functions exactly like a `Namespace`. It solves your problem.

Comment: My updated answer makes everything clearer hopefully. You couldn't have a simpler implementation of the class: `class MyNamespace: pass`

Comment: I'll now take time to digest this and experiment... Thank you.